# How to test MatSideNav

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am trying to test a component that uses matSidenav.
I want to check that it is open or closed but I cannot get the test working.

How can I get this test to work?

**component**

```
export class ItemActionsComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @ViewChild('drawer', { static: true }) drawer: MatSidenav;
  ...other stuff...

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    const showActionsChange = changes['showActions'];
    if (!showActionsChange) {
      return;
    }

    if (showActionsChange.currentValue) {
      this.drawer.open();
    } else {
      this.drawer.close();
    }
  }
}
```

**template**

```
<mat-drawer-container class="example-container"
    [hasBackdrop]="false">
    <mat-drawer #drawer
        [mode]="'Over'"
        position="end">
        <app-notifications-action-buttons [data]="notificationEntryItem"></app-notifications-action-buttons>
    </mat-drawer>
    <mat-drawer-content>
        {{content}}
    </mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

**spec**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-notifications-action-buttons',
    template: '<div></div>',
})
class FakeNotificationsActionButtonsComponent {
    @Input() data: any;
}

describe('ItemActionsComponent', () => {

    let loader: HarnessLoader;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ItemActionsComponent>;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [MatSidenavModule, NoopAnimationsModule],
            declarations: [ItemActionsComponent, FakeNotificationsActionButtonsComponent]
        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ItemActionsComponent);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        loader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(fixture);
    });

    describe('ngOnChanges', () => {
        it('should show side draw when showAction is true', async () => {
            const expected = true;
            const [sideDraw] = await loader.getAllHarnesses(MatDrawerHarness);
            fixture.componentInstance.ngOnChanges({
                showActions: new SimpleChange(null, expected, null)
            });
            fixture.detectChanges();
            expect(sideDraw.isOpen).toEqual(expected);
        });
    });
});
```

I have looked through the docs and tried the `MatSidenavHarness` and tried changing `toEqual` to `toBe` but nothing has worked